# Unmet dependencies installing gazebo_ros_pkgs

Tags: ros, gazebo, ubuntu, dependencies, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everybody,

I am relatively new to ROS and Gazebo, so you will most likely be seeing my questions here a lot. Anyway, I was trying to set up ROS and Gazebo on a new computer, a LATITUDE | D830 from Used Computer Warehouse. I installed 14.04 Ubuntu in place of Windows, and proceeded to install ROS Indigo and Gazebo. While following the instructions at http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing, I got this long error message upon the input of the command sudo apt-get install `ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-pkgs ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-control`:

```
skyguyjedi@skyguyjedi-Latitude-D830:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-pkgs ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-control
[sudo] password for skyguyjedi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-control : Depends: gazebo2 but it is not going to be installed
                                 Depends: libsdformat1 but it is not going to be installed
                                 Depends: ros-indigo-gazebo-ros but it is not going to be installed
 ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-pkgs : Depends: ros-indigo-gazebo-plugins but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: ros-indigo-gazebo-ros but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

As far as I can tell, I'm missing some dependencies that these files need to be installed, but I cannot figure out what these dependencies are, or where to find them. Any assistance, of course, extremely appreciated. I know that this is a rookie problem, but my limited googling skills were unable to turn up another error of this type.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202615/unmet-dependencies-installing-gazebo_ros_pkgs/) by [connor.novak](https://answers.ros.org/users/19957/connor.novak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-02-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Though not entirely sure from your problem description, haven't you already have different version of `Gazebo` installed? If so workaround is seen [in a previous question](http://answers.ros.org/question/191475/how-to-make-ros-indigo-work-with-gazebo-4/).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [connor.novak](https://answers.ros.org/users/19957/connor.novak/) on 2015-02-06**:
Yes, you're right here. I don't know if I had already installed a previous version or not, but the issue that I found was compatibility between versions of ROS and Gazebo. I had to uninstall gazebo4 and install gazebo2, and no more problems! Thanks for your help,